# Capitalization after speech?

Tags: grammaticality

It hasn't explicitly been taught to me what the rules are after speech, especially regarding capitalisation.

1. "Hello?" called June to the yellow figure.
2. "Hello?" Called June to the yellow figure.

I'm pretty sure #1 is correct, but should the second one be corrected?

Comment: (2) is incorrect, as the sentence carries on after the quotation marks are closed. Only capitalise when starting a new sentence. _June called "Hello?" There was no reply._

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks! If you made that an answer, I'd tick it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a lowercase letter** after a quotation if the quotation is part of the sentence (and of course if the word in question isn't a proper noun).

In your example,

> "Hello?" called June to the yellow figure.

the quotation "Hello?" is the [direct object](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/directobject.htm) of the sentence -- it's what *June called*.

The thing that may throw you here is the rare [inversion of subject and object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93subject), which in English
is limited to a kind of affected literary style, most often with quotations (and Yoda).

So, use "called" here with a lowercase "c".